# Mobile nav being covered by container Div (not stretching enough)

Tags: css

I'm running into a problem with the mobile version of a site I'm working on. I added the following CSS to the nav menu to make all of the list items full width and stretch across the length of the nav bar (for desktop users).

```
.menu {
width:100%;
border:0px solid black;
border-bottom-left-radius: 8px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
}

.menu ul {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

.menu li {
list-style: none;
text-align: center;
width: 14.285%; /* fallback for non-calc() browsers */
width: calc(100% / 7);
box-sizing: border-box;
}

/*
@media only screen {
.menu li {
 width:100%;
 width: calc(100%/1);
}
}
*/

.main-nav { 
border: 0px solid black;
border-bottom-left-radius: 8px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
}


.menu li.menu-item-128 {
border:0px solid black;
border-bottom-left-radius:8px; 
border-collapse:collapse; 
}

.menu li.menu-item-128 a {
border:0px solid black;
border-bottom-left-radius:8px;  
border-collapse:collapse;
}



.menu li.menu-item-642 {
border:0px solid black;
border-top-right-radius:0px;
border-bottom-right-radius:8px; 

}

.menu li.menu-item-642 a {
border:0px solid black;
border-top-right-radius:0px;
border-bottom-right-radius:8px;  
}
```

The .menu li rules are what's causing this problem (http://s22.postimg.org/watzsv0wx/mobile_Nav.jpg)

I want it to look like this 
(http://s8.postimg.org/x0brxplhx/mobile_Nav2.jpg)

But the only way I've managed to get the mobile nav menu to look normal is by commenting out the .menu li rules, which prevents the list items from properly stretching in desktop view. The "@media only screen" was my attempt at resolving the problem, but it didn't really work out.

Comment: How about something like `@media screen and (max-width:480px)`?

Comment: Could work, but not exactly sure what rule to add that will still maintain the desktop "menu li" rules, while getting rid of the overlapping issue in mobile.